# schedule apex class in developr console

Tags: salesforce, apex

I was trying to schedule batch apex class using schedule apex class in developer console, but I am not able to schedule it.

Here is my code :

```
schedulefieldupdtebatch sc = new schedulefieldupdtebatch();
System.schedule('Job1', '0 * * * * ?', new scjob());
System.schedule('Job2', '0 15 * * * ?', new scjob());
```

Am getting the error as

> invalid type scjob.

Answer (score 0):

Signature for System.schedule method is given below, for more details please check [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_schedule) or [details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)

```
public static String schedule(String jobName, String cronExpression, Object schedulableClass)
```

Assuming schedulefieldupdtebatch is a SchedulableClass, you can execute below code snippet in developer console.

```
/*Apex code snippet*/ 

//Instantiate Schedulable batch Schedulefieldupdtebatch
Schedulefieldupdtebatch sc = new Schedulefieldupdtebatch();

//Set Scheduler time Oct 20 10:10 am PST
String schTime = '0 10 10 20 10 ?'; 

//This will execute Batch on coming Oct 20 10:10 a PST. Please check Scheduled job for more details  
System.schedule(’Schedule Dup Batch, schTime, sc); 

/*Apex code snippet*/
```